# Regex for Visual C++ 4.0

Tags: c++, c, regex, visual-c++

context: microsoft mbedded visual c++ 4.0, regular expression, windows vista/xp

How can I inject an opensource package of regular expression in VC4?

I have downloaded a release version of ICU which can be found here:
http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/
But some files were not found such as "i18n/unicode/utypes.h"?

Boost.Regex requires at least VC7.

An other solution is Ragel but it's too complicated for a newbie like me. I'm looking for a more simple solution. Any suggestion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you using a 20 years old compiler?

Comment: I have an old device with a project in VC4. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: buy and new device and compiler ?

Comment: I would be happy if it was simple like that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That header it complains about is specific to Linux, it probably wasn't made with the intent of being compiled on Windows (embedded or not).

I use [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org) in Windows (desktop), my guess is that it will probably compile OK in your embedded environment.

Notice its interface is C, not C++. In my case I wrote a relatively simple wrapper class to ease its use.

[image: PCRE files]

Comment: I copied : "re_comp.h, regcomp.c, regex.c, regex.h, regex_internal.c, regex_internal.h, regexec.c" into my project. But I dont know what to do next. There are some conflicts. I tried to modify by adding/removing including file but still get some error.

Comment: You'll need more than that. I attached an image of that section of my project to the answer. Be careful also not to add modules that are part of  demos and/or test cases (as some of those you mentioned appear to be).

Comment: Also don't add .h files to the VC project; they aren't needed there, and if they are in  the wrong place VC will try to compile them with predictable bad results.

Comment: Finally, if you're compiling the modules inside a single executable, add the macro PCRE_STATIC to the preprocessor, otherwise the functions in the PCRE headers would be declared as external (i.e. residing in a separated DLL).